# What's up with this :nth-child rule?

Tags: css

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pwxjX/)

Specifically, why is my `#sumMenu2 p:nth-child(2)` rule not showing up?

html:

```
<div id="subMenu2">
    <p class="active">Panel View</p>
    <p>Group View</p>
    <p>Photocell Settings</p>
</div>
```

css:

```
#subMenu2 {
    background: pink;
}
#subMenu2 p {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px 25px 5px 25px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
#sumMenu2 p:nth-child(2) {
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you've spelled it #sumMenu2?

```
#sumMenu2 p:nth-child(2) {
border-right: 1px solid black;
border-left: 1px solid black;
```

Comment: No worries, we've all done it!